# Javascript array not getting modified

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some JSON data in the "data" variable.
FORMAT :

```
{
    "0" : {"names":"Pooja, Trivedi"},
    "1" : {"names":"Pooja, Rooster"}
}
```

I need to implement a map so as to count the different names:

```
Pooja = 2
Trivedi = 1
Rooster = 1
```

Here is the implementation:

```
map = new Array();
data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);  //convert JSON to object
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var names = data[i].names.split(','); //split the CSVs
  for (var j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
    if (map[names[j].trim()] === undefined) {
      map[names[j].trim()] = 1;
    } else {
      map[names[j].trim()]++;
    }
  }
console.log(map); //shows progressively filled arrays
}
console.log(map); //shows [], an empty array
```

Inside the loop, the map is updated.
However after the end of the i loop, all we have is an empty array.
How is this to be resolved?

Comment: should be object not array

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. `console.log(map); //shows progressively filled arrays` doesn't even get called. http://jsbin.com/zakalodone/1/edit?js,console

Comment: @charlietfl : I need the keys/names sorted in alphabetical order.

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @Quentin It does get called.

Comment: well `map['String']` isn't array

Comment: Stack has had [most of the bits of JSFiddle that we care about built in](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for the last year. Please put a live demo of a [reproducible test case](http://sscce.org/) in the question itself, not linked to on another site.

Comment: @anurageldorado — No, it doesn't. `data.length` is undefined so it never enters the loop. You can see that on the live demo I linked to.

Comment: Do you have access to ES2015? You can use a `new Map()` which stores key/value pairs in the order they are added

Comment: Are you sure that parseJSON returns an array? According to jQuery documentation it returns an object. If that is the case, you shouldn't use a for loop to iterate over the properties of the object. You should use a for-in loop instead.

Comment: In case it isn't clear, `data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);  //convert JSON to array` does not result in an array. Is this by design?

Comment: I suspect this isn't your actual code, and somewhere in the conversion to an example, you lost something. If you set `data` to be a JSON representation of an array (rather than an object as you currently have), your code does run, but then the last `console.log` shows the the same as the previous, i.e. not `[]` as you say in the question

Comment: @AdrianLynch : I meant object.

Comment: well then, as has been pointed out, the loop will never run because your object won't have a `length` property

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't want to use `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)` to traverse your data object, because a Javascript object doesn't have a length property like an array would. So, use a `for (var i in data)` instead, to traverse all the keys in the object.

This works:

```
var data = {
  "0" : {"names":"Pooja, Trivedi"},
  "1" : {"names":"Pooja, Rooster"}
}

var map = {};
for (var i in data) {
  var names = data[i].names.split(',');
  for (var j in names) {
    var name = names[j].trim();
    if (map[name]) {
      map[name]++;
    } else {
      map[name] = 1;
    }
  }
  console.log(map); //shows progressively filled arrays
}
console.log(map); //shows the full array
```

And you don't want to use an array as your map. You should instead use an object.

Answer (score -1):

I like this version better:

```
var data = {
    "0" : {"names":"Pooja, Trivedi"},
    "1" : {"names":"Pooja, Rooster"}
};

var nameCounts = {};

for (var item in data) {
    data[item].names.split(", ").forEach(function (name) {
        if (name in nameCounts) {
            nameCounts[name]++;
        } else {
            nameCounts[name] = 1;
        }
    });
}

console.log(nameCounts);
```